# How to assign foreignkey in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use the Dynamo DB. I am trying to test the Dynamo DB Tables But I can't Get Foreign Key in this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? DynamoDB is not a relational database. You should say what your actual problem is rather than asking for a specific solution. Also, your comments above do not add anything to the conversation.

Comment: Shall we define Foreign Key in Dynamo DB?

Comment: Foreign Key Like in SQL Server.

Comment: @MikeKobit Are you Get it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

DynamoDB does not have foreign keys. It is a NoSQL database that doesn't support that kind of relational data.  There is no data integrity maintained between tables, so this sort of behavior is not built in. If you want to have this sort of behavior, you will have to model your data storage in DynamoDB a different way.

From the [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/) explaining that it **is not** a relational database:

> While Amazon DynamoDB tackles the core problems of database
>   scalability, management, performance, and reliability, it does not
>   have all the functionality of a relational database. It does not
>   support complex relational queries (e.g. joins) or complex
>   transactions. If your workload requires this functionality, or you are
>   looking for compatibility with an existing relational engine, you may
>   wish to run a relational engine on Amazon RDS or Amazon EC2. While
>   relational database engines provide robust features and functionality,
>   scaling a workload beyond a single relational database instance is
>   highly complex and requires significant time and expertise.

Comment: along this vein of question - is it ever a good idea to use the hash key of another table, say `Users.id`, in another table, say `Payments.id`, so you can directly search `Payments.id == Users.id` to create a foreign-key like mapping in Dynamo and allow direct querying?

The only thing I can see is that it's not self documenting unless you call it Payments.userId and set that as the hash key but then you lose consistency across all your DB's when naming hash key indexes such as Payments.Id, Users.Id, Wallet,Id, etc.

Comment: I've just realized you can get foreign-key like relationships with global secondary indexes and if you need a sorted foreign-key to prevent scanning and filtering then you can add a range key to the global secondary index. This should allow you to still maintain unique IDs for each distinct table while still adding a foreign-key like queryability and also preserve the best part about range keys which is automatic sorting and key condition expression comparison operations such as >, <, <=, >=, and !=.

Answer (score 2):

Dynomodb does not have foreign keys. Dynomodb is non-relational database, but it contains tables .