# Updating database keys where one table's keys refer to another's

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I have two tables in DynamoDB. One has data about homes, one has data about businesses. The homes table has a list of the closest businesses to it, with walking times to each of them. That is, the homes table has a list of IDs which refer to items in the businesses table. Since businesses are constantly opening and closing, both these tables need to be updated frequently.

The problem I'm facing is that, when either one of the tables is updated, the other table will have incorrect data until it is updated itself. To make this clearer: let's say one business closes and another one opens. I could update the businesses table first to remove the old business and add the new one, but the homes table would then still refer to the now-removed business. Similarly, if I updated the homes table first to refer to the new business, the businesses table would not yet have this new business' data yet. Whichever table I update first, there will always be a period of time where the two tables are not in synch.

What's the best way to deal with this problem? One way I've considered is to do all the updates to a secondary database and then swap it with my primary database, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign foreignkey in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431758/how-to-assign-foreignkey-in-dynamodb)  Dynamo does not offer referential integrity, so you have to take care of it in your code, or switch database engine.

Comment: @Nic3500 it seems to me he's asking for help exactly about how to handle this in his code, he didn't ask "how do I set a foreign key in Dynamo". He presented the way he thought implementing and asked for help. Am I wrong?

Comment: @colinjstewart I presume a single business could be associated to multiple homes as well, right? Thus, you have a many-to-many relationship, is that correct?

Comment: @RenatoByrro In deed.  But the potential duplicate link I provided hints at a way to do it using other mechanisms in the comments to the accepted answer.

Comment: @RenatoByrro this is correct, homes can be associated with multiple businesses and vice versa.

Comment: You certainly know, but what you're looking for is an **Aatomic transaction**. Dynamo doesn't offer it, but there's a workaround that could ensure atomicity in a very high portion of the operations, say 99.9999% of cases. If this is mission-critical for you, meaning, you cannot accepts 0.0001% chance of the atomicity principle being violated within a transaction, then you must look for another database. [Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/
) supports Atomic transactions. So, would a non-100% workaround be acceptable for you in Dynamo?

Comment: @RenatoByrro Yes, a non-100% workaround would be fine. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo only offers atomic operations on the item level, not transaction level, but you can have something similar to an atomic transaction by enforcing some rules in your application.

Let's say you need to run a *transaction* with two operations:

1. Delete `Business(id=123)` from the table.
2. Update `Home(id=456)` to remove association with `Business(id=123)` from the `home.businesses` array.

Here's what you can do to mimic a *transaction*:

### Generate a timestamp for locking the items

Let's say our current timestamp is `1234567890`. Using a timestamp will allow you to clean up failed transactions (I'll explain later).

### Lock the two items

Update both `Business-123` and `Home-456` and set an attribute `lock=1234567890`.

**Do not change any other attributes yet on this update operation!**

Use a `ConditionalExpression` (check the [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) and [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ConditionExpression)) to verify that `attribute_not_exists(lock)` before updating. This way you're sure there's no other process using the same items.

### Handle update lock responses

Check if both updates succeeded to Home and Business. If yes to both, it means you can proceed with the actual changes you need to make: delete the `Business-123` and update the `Home-456` removing the Business association.

For extra care, also use a `ConditionExpression` in both updates again, but now ensuring that `lock == 1234567890`. This way you're extra sure no other process overwrote your lock.

If both updates succeed again, you can consider the two items updated and consistent to be read by other processes. To do this, run a third update removing the `lock` attribute from both items.

When one of the operations fail, you may try again X times for example. If it fails all X times, make sure the process cleans up the other `lock` that succeeded previously.

### Enforce the transaction lock throught your code

Always use a `ConditionExpression` in any part of your code that may update/delete Home and Business items. This is crucial for the solution to work.

When reading Home and Business items, you'll need to do this (*this may not be necessary in all reads, you'll decide if you need to ensure consistency from start to finish while working with an item read from DB*):

1. Retrieve the item you want to read
2. Generate a lock timestamp
3. Update the item with `lock=timestamp` using a `ConditionExpression`
4. If the update succeeds, continue using the item normally; if not, wait one or two seconds and try again;
5. When you're done, update the item removing the `lock`

### Regularly clean up failed transactions

Every minute or so, run a background process to look for potentially failed transactions. If your processes take at max 60 seconds to finish and there's an item with `lock` value older than, say 5 minutes (remember `lock` value is the time the transaction started), it's safe to say that this transaction failed at some point and whatever process running it didn't properly clean up the locks.

This background job would ensure that no items keep locked for eternity.

> Beware this implementation do not assure a real atomic and consistent transaction in the sense traditional ACID DBs do. If this is mission critical for you (e.g. you're dealing with financial transactions), do not attempt to implement this. Since you said you're ok if atomicity is broken on rare failure occasions, you may live with it happily. ;)

Hope this helps!